# angular js and asp.net mvc 4 sample application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am looking for a angular js and asp.net mvc 4 sample application. I found some very good samples with for angular js but not so much with insert , add, delete to a database.
Does anyone have any examples available?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are 2-3 project templates for AngularJS and MVC integration

ASP.Net MVC 4 template for AngularJS SPA
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc6c9c5f-2846-4822-899f-a6c295cd4f2b (Created by me :)

and

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83

Breeze AngularJS template
http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeangular-template

Comment: Tempted to know! please tell me how do you create a visualsttudio template?

Comment: @Bellash very simple scenario - create and config your project. Than File->Export template.

Comment: I'm using your template but I have some problems to find out how to resolve a routeprovider config mapping for something like /home/{action}/{id}.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another tutorial on how to integrate Angular.js and ASP.NET MVC5 (http://xombe.com/2014/02/17/combine-angular-js-with-asp-net-mvc/).  The project files don't have INSERT/ADD/DELETE to a DB, but it demonstrates the core concept of passing a model to Angular.js, updating the model from a Controller, and having Angular.js update the view.

**Note**: I didn't know about Breeze.js.  I'm going to check that out next :-)  Looks like it could be a great fit.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a client side technology so doesn't have direct access to database but using of a WebAPI or other REST services including cloud databases etc. Also ASP.NET MVC is not a good choice for Angular - Angular uses own routing and templating system so Web Pages is more applicable. John Papa has posted series of guidelines on [his web site](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/). Also take a look at [TodoMVC project](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/angularjs/#/). It's not exactly guide you are looking for but a good point to start.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is Web API tutorial.

Search tutorials for Web API by REST standard, using Entity Framework. After the tutorial you will be able to create your own integration very easily.